# Ruby Rack on Phusion NoMethod Error for Table Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, passenger, nomethoderror

Error message:
    undefined method `AdminUser' for # (NoMethodError)
Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::UnknownError

AdminUser is a table in my db. The worst part, is that I never even use the table or call it anywhere from my code. 
The only place where I even mention AdminUser is in my admin_user.rb models -

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
  scope :named, lambda {|first,last| where(:first_name => first, :last_name => last)}

end
```

And page.rb Model

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :subject
  has_many :sections
  has_and_belongs_to_many :editors, :class_name => "AdminUser"
end
```

And in section.rb Model

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base

  AdminUser has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
  belongs_to :page

end
```

That's it. There is 0 other mention of AdminUser - It is something I haven't even begun using in my app. 
I don't have a problem when running my app locally, but on Ubuntu, with Passenger and Apache2, Phusion refuses to load my app.

For reference (I'm fairly new to RoR and Ubuntu(linux based OS's)) - but yes I did run rake db:migrate, yes I did install Passenger as a gem, and yes I am using mysql2 gem to connect to my db. And of course, I did install and start mysql service on ubuntu. (Also, I did create the db, the user, and - basically the rake db:migrate worked 100%).

Can you please help me, I'm loosing my mind - been having this problem for 2 days now - and have no idea where to look.

Environment: Rails 3.2.2, Ruby 1.9.3-p125

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `AdminUser` from `section.rb`

Comment: hmm removing that all I get is the standard 500.html - something went wrong - and no logs about it...

Comment: Ok so the issue is that the code above works in development but throws the error in production... Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Maybe because, in production rails preloads all your classes. Is section.rb ever loaded in development? i.e. are you actively using `Section` in development?